# Is it OK to have Behavior Driven Tests overlap with Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, tdd, bdd

I am struggling with the concept of BDD mixed in with TDD at the moment, particularly when tests overlap.

Such as let’s say I have a unit test verifying that when I add two numbers together it returns the sum. Next unit test says that when I multiply two numbers together, it returns the product.

The requirement from the customer is that they must be able to multiply and add numbers at the same time. Writing this Behavior test effectively overlaps the two unit tests, already testing those features. There’s a good chance that a behavior test like this could identify a problem with the requirement of being able to add and multiply at the same time... so I feel it is useful.

But I feel like some people may consider this test redundant, because like I said it is technically overlapping unit tests... is this normal and acceptable?

Also, what about behavior tests that are using mocks and not the real system? Looking online it appears there’s no harsh requirements on that, but I feel if the scenario is specific enough it’s perfectly fine to use mocks?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a conceptual question about software development and is a better fit for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Related: [How to use unit tests when using BDD?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/274562/118878).

Answer (score 1):

When you use BDD and TDD together, there will be some overlap. However both are used for two different purposes. BDD should not be used just as a Test framework. BDD is mainly used for cross functional collaboration. In BDD Teams collaborate and derive real world examples written in natural language. This shared understanding, is then, only then, is taken and automated.

The scenarios that BDD typically covers are end to end process. As part of BDD, the session in your tests are shared. For an example, you could have a following scenario:

> Given the users login successfully
> When the user applies for a job
> Then a job application number should be returned

In the above scenario, in the Given step, the underlying scripts could call a login API to get the token and passes it on to subsequent steps. In other words the state is shared. Also in the above scenario, database or a website or a REST endpoint or MQ or any endpoint/interface could be called to send and verify the results.

Whereas in TDD, the session is not shared and all external endpoints/databases are mocked. Only the functionality of the code is tested. When both BDD and TDD are used, you are bound to have some overlaps. In the above example, you could have a TDD that tests only the login functionality by say mocking the REST API that validates the login.

As I have mentioned above, you shouldn't consider BDD as a test framework but as a collaboration tool and automation comes as great benefit.

Here is an article I put together which explains the difference between TDD and BDD
https://blog.nocodebdd.com/bdd-vs-tdd/